# Retrieving app_label from a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I programmatically get the app_label from any model object passed to a function so that I can serialise it to XML?

In this example model_unicode is the name of the model, and object is the pre filtered model object. I do need get_model() for later on

```
def model_to_xml(object, model_unicode):
    model_list = object
    model_name = ""
    model_app_label = ???
    model = get_model(model_app_label,model_unicode)
```

Okm's Test Output

```
try:
    print object.model
except:
    print "not Queryset"
try:
    print object.__class__
except:
    print "not Instance of Model"
```

Output:

```
<class 'jmsdirectory.contacts.models.Supplies'>
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Comment: You don't need `get_model`, just use `object.model`, if the `object` is a `QuerySet`, or `object.__class__` if `object` is an instance of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> User._meta.app_label
'auth'
```

[More information](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/04/working-models/) you can get from `_meta`

Comment: There is not `User` actually...The op is trying to find one

Comment: As @okm pointed out you can get `Model` class from `obj.__class__`

Comment: so that would make the final code to do it, obj.__class__._meta.app_label ?

Comment: Nope, both versions of them fail, but i have a starting point at least :)

Answer (score 0):

To get app_label for an instance:

```
user._meta.app_label
```

Tested in Django 4.